# SQL Pivot with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, pivot

The SQL Pivot command seems difficult at least. I've read a lot about it, and been tinkering with this query for a while, but all I get are really obscure error messages that don't help, like "The column name 'Id' was specified multiple times.." or "The multi-part identifier X could not be bound."

Our database collects client answers to questions. I'd like to create a table which contains a row for each client, and columns for each question (ID) they've answered and the AVG ResponseTime across all times that user has logged in. This is made more difficult as the UserId isn't directly stored in the UserSessionData table, it's stored in the UserSession table, so I have to do a join first, which seems to complicate the issue.

The tables I'm trying to pivot are roughly of the following form:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserSessionData](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserSessionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserWasCorrect] [bit] NULL,
[ResponseTime] [float] NULL,
[QuestionId] [int] NULL)
--This table contains user answers to a number of questions.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserSession](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SessionCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
--This table contains details of the user's login session.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QuestionText] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[GameId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
--This table contains question details
```

I'll continue trying to mangle a solution, but if anyone can shed any light (or suggest an easier method than PIVOT to achieve the desired result), then that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: When writing your query to pivot the data, reference the columns by full name. eg, [Question].[Id], [UserSessionData].[ID] etc

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've got the same column names in multiple tables so after you've done the join the pivot sees multiple columns all the same name. Have a look at my example below:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        usd.Id AS usdId
        ,UserSessionId
        ,UserWasCorrect
        ,ResponseTime
        ,QuestionId
        ,us.Id AS usId
        ,SessionCode
        ,UserId
        ,Description
        ,GameId
        ,qu.Id AS quId
        ,QuestionText
    FROM #UserSessionData usd
    LEFT JOIN #UserSession us
    ON usd.UserSessionId = us.Id
    LEFT JOIN #Question qu
    ON usd.QuestionId = qu.Id
) AS tbl PIVOT (
    -- As no example data was provided 'quest' & 'voyage are just random values I put in. Change the pivot statement to match what you want
    MIN(ResponseTime) FOR SessionCode IN (quest, voyage)
) AS pvt
```

'quest' and 'voyage' are example data of the rows contents in the Column `SessionCode`. This will need to be changed to your columns contents. In `PIVOT`s and `UNPIVOT`s you cannot use a query to get these values and they have to be statically put in. You could use dynamic SQL to generate the values however this is usually heavily advised against

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for that. I'd got somewhere similar to this, but I don't understand exactly what I have to replace the terms "quest" and "voyage" terms with?

For example, I'd like the "quest" column to be filled with the MIN(ResponseTime), which is a column in [UserSessionData] that I omitted from the example above.

Also, where can I add a WHERE clause to the UserSessionData SELECT in order to filter some rows out?

Comment: Why did you omit it from your question? The WHERE clause would go in the inner query (where the tables are joined together). Can you update your question with exactly what you want instead of me stabbing around in the dark?

Comment: Sorry dude. Updated. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Many thanks again - This *mostly* addresses my requirements, however I still need some sort of aggregation to ensure that all the UserSessionData appears groups by client (so there is only one row for each user). 

This is in the original question, but perhaps I'm not very clear.

Comment: Without example data it is quite difficult to grasp what you're really trying to achieve. If you uploaded some example data (both inputs and outputs) someone might be able to help you. [Upload your setup to here and post the link](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I can't really upload the data. The part I'm struggling with is how to actually have values appear in the fields you've named "quest" and "voyage". Where do I specify which data fills those columns?

Comment: Just make some data up. It doesn't need to be the same. Just 3 lines of example data for each table that will work

Comment: Whatever I enter in that SQLFiddle is says "Script Error", even if I just paste the Create from above. :/ 

Added data here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_kMoYinePjeY2w0SFBCOWRMU0E?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you find time to take a look Tom?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data set you're trying to get out and I'll try and have a look